# How to find the surface area of a cylinder given only diameter and length?

Tags: area

The exact question is,

"Your Siberian Husky, Emma, and her Husky-Shepherd friend, Luca, destroy your fence pickets in the backyard.

To repair the fence, you buy new pickets and galvanized nails with a diameter of 1.9 mm and a length of 5.6 cm. Find the surface area of the nails in mm2. Assume the nails to be perfect cylinders".

Please help, I feel that my TA forgot to add volume or something cause this seems impossible I've been looking for ways (for three hours), but ultimately it seemed that I would either need area or volume of some sort!

Comment: This isn't the worst non sequitur I've seen in a word problem, but it's pretty bad. I don't think anyone have ever been interested in the surface area of nails they're using. The galvanizer might be, but not the user. Rant over.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Picture the surface area as a rectangle that wraps around the cylinder. The side lengths of the rectangle are the circumference of the circle and the height (length) of the cylinder. Then you would just add the area of both circles.

Comment: Yes, but you're not given the area of the rectangle only the length. Two missing variables!

Comment: You can find the circumference of the circles, because you have the diameter. So that's one side. The other side is the length.